# Case internal: of swift 2 in swift 3

Tags: swift3, migration

I'm migrating from swift 2 to swift 3, I'm new in swift and I do not know how this would go in swift 3

Example of my code:

```
Switch self {
             Case .decode:
              Return -26275
             Case internal:
               Return -26276
 }
```

The error (Expected pattern) is in

```
Case internal:
```

I would greatly appreciate your help

Comment: Keywords `switch` `case` `return` are *lowercase*, even in Swift 2. – Apart from that: `internal` is a keyword, and cases must have a leading dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing a leading `.`

```
case .internal:
```

Comment: `internal` already existed in Swift 2. The new access modifiers in Swift 3 are `open` and `fileprivate`.

Comment: What changed in Swift 3 is that you can use keywords at  many places (*without* escaping) where it wasn't allowed before. Here: `case .internal` without backticks inside the switch-statement.